Cambiar textos en placeholder de Tutor LMS
Trato de cambiar los textos de los placeholder en todas las casillas a excepción de la de "nombre de usuario". El problema es que estas no cuentan con un ID específico, por lo que estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente "sin éxito", por ejemplo, la casilla "Número telefónico":
document.getElementsByName("phone_number").placeholder="new text for email";

También intenté con:
document.getElementsByName("phone_number")[0].placeholder="new text for email";


El formulario está elaborado en diferentes columnas tutor-row y comparten el mismo div class tutor-col-12 tutor-col-sm-6 tutor-col-md-12 tutor-col-lg-6 tutor-mb-32 ¿por lo que es posible que se deba usar el selector :nth-child()?
Estos cambios los inserto usando Code Snippet en wordpress

¿Porque no comparas el atributo name del input para identificarlo?. if (elemento_input.getAttribute("name")=="phone_number")elemento_input.setAttribute("placeholder","otro placeholder");

El codigo de arriba funciona con un bucle: for (let elemento_input of document.getElementsByClassName("phone_number")){
